# MATLAB: Center displayed text?

Tags: matlab

How can I center the text printed by `display('the text')`?

Eg, like the text you get when entering matlab.

A function to get the width of the current terminal will do to (I'll figure it out from there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a fairly new version of matlab you can do:

```
sz=get(0, 'CommandWindowSize');
command_line_width = sz(1);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use a mex file:
see this link http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/25315